# Converting Complex type XML to Classes

Tags: c#, xml, class, deserialization, setter

I was wondering how can I convert this complex type xml into a Model or classes?

I have my attempt below and I was wondering if someone can double check it for me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<lot_information lot_exp_date="XXXX-XX-XX" lot_number="123456">
<components> 
<component control="A" ref="A" family="XXXXX" component="12" id="1A1">
<target>42</target> 
<min>12</min >
<max>90</max>
<number>10</number> 
</component>
<component control="A" ref="A" family="XXXXX" component="13" id="1A2B3C">
<target>42</target>
<min>12</min>
<max>90</max>
<number>10</number>
</component>
</components> 
<families>
<control family="XXXXX" ctrl="ctrlA"/> 
<control family="XXXXX" ctrl="ctrlB"/>
<control family="XXXXX" ctrl="ctrlC"/> 
<control family="XXXXX" ctrl="ctrlD"/> 
</families> </lot_information>
```

Here is my model class:

```
[Serializable]
public class LotInformation
{
    public string exp_date { get; set; }
    public Array[] lot_information { get; set; } 
    public int lot_number {get; set;} 

}
[Serializable]
public class Components {

    public Array[] ComponentControl { get; set; }
    public string ref { get; set; }
    public string family { get; set; }
    public int component { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

}
[Serializable]
public class Family
{
    private string[] controlFamily { get; set; }
    private string ctrl { get; set; }

}
```

Just double check that it makes sense if I'm using an array to keep the structure of the XML file in that format or not.

Eventually, this is going to be deserialized so I am wondering if the above makes sense.

EDIT: Please no comments on automated tools to help me. They make it more complicated. I want to write clean code and see if what I have makes sense. Automated tools give me unsigned integers, empty namespaces, and other unnecessary refinements.

Comment: Do you have control over the XML?  Or are you stuck with it and just trying to deserialize it?

Comment: @Erik Phillips, stuck with it and deserializing it. The only control I have right now is creating the class based on the structure of the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml data is invalid currently, changing `<Components>` to `<components>` should be valid.

If you have Visual studio 2013, you can paste the XML to classes.
Can look ugly but at least you should be sure it is correct.

Copy the XML data, then in Visual studio.
Edit -> Paste special -> Paste XML as Classes

**EDIT**

Updated with code sample
This is what I get when I clean the auto-generated code,
there is no information whether the fields are from attributes or not in the XML. This can be updated with annotations for the properties.

I cleaned up the code by simplifying types to string or int and used auto-properties instead of explicit properties and removed auto generated xml-attributes.

```
[Serializable]
public class Lot_information {    
    public Component[] components { get; set; }
    public Control[] families { get; set; }
    public string lot_exp_date { get; set;}
    public int lot_number { get; set;}
}
[Serializable]
public class Component {    
    public int target { get; set; }    
    public int min { get; set; }    
    public int max { get; set; }    
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string control { get; set; }
    public string @ref { get; set; }
    public string family { get; set; }
    public int component { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Control {
    public string family { get; set; }
    public string ctrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the capital Components to components change. I fixed it. I don't want to use an automated tool. I would rather just someone go over what I have and see if it makes sense. The automated tool gave me things like uint but I don't think that's necessary and empty namespaces. It ruined my code vs. helping me.

Comment: Thank you! It seems fine. I'll double check it a bit later.

Comment: I have a question, if I wanted to create database tables using entity framework and I need to tranfer over the Component and Control arrays. How do I do that? Right now I labeled them as [Xmlelement] instead of attribute and they did not transfer over to my database table. I think I have to use virtual icollection but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XSD.EXE tool

1. Xsd yourxml.xml

to get the yourxml.xsd file. Then

1. Xsd yourxml.xsd /classes

this will generate the class file automatically.

Comment: That tools makes everything complicated and spits out unnecessary tags. I have used it as a reference but I'd prefer someone to double check what I currently have.